# How can I group and count items on an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, grouping, counting

I have an object with this structure:

```
[{category:'A',sub:'A-1'},
 {category:'B',sub:'A-1'},
 {category:'A',sub:'B-1'},
 {category:'A',sub:'A-1'}];
```

and I want to group by category and count the repetitions of the 'sub' property to get something like this:

```
[
    {category:'A',data:[{sub:'A-1',count:2},{sub:'B-1',count:1}]},
    {category:'B',data:[{sub:'A-1',count:1}]}
]
```

I think I almost there, but I cannot figure out how to get it right. Here is my code:

```
let myData:any[]=[{category:'A',sub:'A-1'},{category:'B',sub:'A-1'},{category:'A',sub:'B-1'},{category:'A',sub:'A-1'}];

let categories= Array.from(new Set(myData.map(x => x.category)));

let statistics=categories.map(x=>{
  let j={category:x,data:[]};
  j.data.push( myData.filter(a=>a.category==x)
  .reduce((a, c) => (a[c.sub] = (a[c.sub] || 0) + 1, a), Object.create(null)));

  return j;
})
console.log(JSON.stringify( statistics));
```

But the output generate it is this:

```
[
 {"category":"A","data":[{"A-1":2,"B-1":1}]},
 {"category":"B","data":[{"A-1":1}]}
]
```

Comment: Now imagine you have a task to turn `{"A-1":2,"B-1":1}` into `[{sub:'A-1',count:2},{sub:'B-1',count:1}]`. How would you do it?

Comment: Hi @zerkms, I do not know how to do it. That's why I asked

Comment: Hint #1: iterate over the `{"A-1":2,"B-1":1}` using `Object.keys` or `Object.entries`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my code with @zerkms´s hint #1. Iterate over `{"A-1":2,"B-1":1}` with `Object.entries` . Here is the code:

```
let myData:any[]=[{category:'A',sub:'A-1'},{category:'B',sub:'A-1'},{category:'A',sub:'B-1'},{category:'A',sub:'A-1'}];

let categories= Array.from(new Set(myData.map(x => x.category)));

let statistics=categories.map(x=>{
  let categoryItem={category:x,data:[]};

  let subItem= myData.filter(my=>my.category==x)
  .reduce((a, c) => (a[c.sub] = (a[c.sub] || 0) + 1, a), Object.create(null));

   for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(subItem)) {
     categoryItem.data.push({'sub':key,'count':value})
  }
  return categoryItem;

})

console.log(JSON.stringify( statistics));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code a bit and now it does reproduce the desire output, take a look.
 I feel, we can optimize this code further.

```js
let myData = [{ category: 'A', sub: 'A-1' },
    { category: 'B', sub: 'A-1' }, { category: 'A', sub: 'B-1' }, { category: 'A', sub: 'A-1' }];
let x;
let categories = Array.from(new Set(myData.map(x => x.category)));
let distinctSubs = [];
let counterObj = { sub: '', count: 0 };
let counterObjArr = [];
let statistics = categories.map(x => {
    distinctSubs = Array.from(new Set(myData.filter(p => p.category === x).map(y => y.sub)));
    counterObjArr.length = 0;
    let j = { category: x, data: Object.assign([], counterObjArr) };
    distinctSubs.forEach(s => {
        j.data.push({ sub: s, count: myData.filter(z => z.category === x && z.sub === s).length });
    });
    return j;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(statistics));
```

Comment: Hi @Akash, thanks for your help. I end up using `Object.Entries` after `reduce` to trasnform `{"A-1":2,"B-1":1}` into `{sub:'A-1',count:2},{sub:'B-1',count:1}`

Comment: Awesome.  Happy to know you finally did it.